# No zoom options while recording video

Tags: 8.0, lumia

I am using Nokia Lumia 520. There is no zooming option available while recording video. Is there any   windows app supports zoom?

Comment: Have you tried pinch to zoom while a) taking a picture and b) taking video - it should work on all Windows Phone 8 devices

Comment: @Neil - Yeah. I tried. While taking pictures, zoom is working. While recording video, we can't zoom in/out & we can't pause the recording in between. We need to zoom before starting recording. It's pathetic.

Comment: I just checked on my Lumia 920, you can only zoom *before* you start recording video, but *not* during.

Comment: I want that too,pause and zoom on Nokia lumia 520,even Nokia 6234 had that option

Answer (score 3):

As you have discovered, this is not possible at this time- not even with an app. Also, Windows Phone is not the only OS that doesn't support this. [iOS has added this feature only in the upcoming iOS 7](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2013/06/ios-7-finally-lets-you-zoom-while-recording-video-on-your-iphone/).

The best you can do at this time is to hope that [the next version of Windows Phone (8.1) has this feature](http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/purported-windows-phone-81-blue-leak-shows-notification-center-more).

In the meanwhile, do upvote these suggestions on the official Windows Phone User Voice site:

- ["Enable PAUSE and ZOOM options while recording a video"](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3726421-enable-pause-and-zoom-options-while-recording-a-vi)
- ["video record zooming option buttons while recording, and and pause buttons."](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2282565-video-record-zooming-option-buttons-while-recordin)
- ["Enable focusing while recording video by tap"](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3151167-enable-focusing-while-recording-video-by-tap)

Comment: Karan, Thanks for the info. I will surely do this.

Comment: I just tried with the built in camera app and it didn't work. But with the new Nokia Camera Pro I could zooming while recording video. Lumia 920